# Passing reference of HTMLElement to Polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<div id="main">
  ...
  <x-element></x-element>
  ...
</div>
```

How do I pass a reference to `div#main` to `x-element`? I need it so that my iron-list element inside `x-element` can point to `div#main` as the `scroll-target`.

Comment: Please add more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can place `<content></content>` inside your `iron-list` element and then pass your div element inside `x-element` tags. This way Polymer will render your div tag inside the `iron-list`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution)